# being built vs built

Tags: prepositions

Would someone describe the difference between these two sentences? Are they both syntactically correct with the different meanings?

> With fewer iPhones built, it is safe to conclude that sales will be lower.

> With fewer iPhones being built, it is safe to conclude that sales will be lower.

Or this one:

> With Twitter and Facebook banned, Telegram accounts for about 40 percent of internet traffic.

> With Twitter and Facebook being banned, Telegram accounts for about 40 percent of internet traffic.

Comment: "Built" is cumulative, and "being built" we are looking at current numbers.